# problem when changing buttons in a cell. swift

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I need to get data from UserDefaults and based on them display the desired button in the cell. Tell me how can this be done? If you insert a condition at the init level, then the data is empty

```
class ItemsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    static let reuseId = "ItemsCollectionViewCell"
    var textItem: String = ""
    var categoryItem: String = ""
    var costItem: Int = 0
    var imageItem: String = ""
    ...
 let addCartButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = .gray
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        button.setTitle("В корзину", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tappedAddCart), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    ...
```

````
class ItemsCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
...
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ItemsCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! ItemsCollectionViewCell
        cell.costItem = cells[indexPath.row].price
        cell.imageItem = cells[indexPath.row].imageUrl
        cell.categoryItem = "test"
        cell.textItem = cells[indexPath.row].title  
        guard let imageUrlnew:URL = URL(string: cells[indexPath.row].imageUrl) else {
                    return cell
                }
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrlnew) else {
          return cell
        }
        cell.mainImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        cell.nameLabel.text = cells[indexPath.row].title
        cell.costLabel.text = String(cells[indexPath.row].price) + " руб."
        cell.nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
        cell.costLabel.textAlignment = .center
        return cell
    }
    ```
````

Comment: The question is unclear. What button**s** (plural) are you talking about ? And what *data from UserDefaults*? By the way if `imageUrl` is a remote URL you are strongly discouraged from loading the data synchronously with `Data(contentsOf`. And why do you call `cells[indexPath.row]` six times to get always the same item?

Comment: @vadian The cell now displays an "add to cart" button. In UserDefaults I put an array with the items added to the cart. At the UICollectionViewCell level, I need to check if this item is in the cart. If there is a product, then hide the button. The name of the product in UICollectionViewCell comes to the textItem variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you add an "add to cart" button to all cells, and set it to hidden. Then, in your cellForItemAt method, check UserDefaults and show/hide the button. (Make sure you always explicitly set the button's hidden state to true or false. Don't assume it is already hidden, since the cell may have been recycled.)